# How many different ordered combinations of N

Tags: python, algorithm, counting

Here is an link to `spoj` problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/GOODB/.
you are given `N, WA, TLE, RE` such that

```
N = WA+TLE+RE
```

how many different ordered combinations of `N` incorrect results (each being WA, TLE, or RE) exist which satisfy their predictions?

and here is my working solution in python

```
import math
mod=10**9+7
def nck(n,k):
    return math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(n-k) * math.factorial(k))

n,w,t,r = map(int, raw_input().split())
print (nck(n,w) * nck(n-w, t)) % mod
```

Here is second approach for the same problem by the assumption that the number of ways to arrange
 n1 a1 's, n2 a2 's, …, nk ak 's in a row is

```
n!/(n1! n2! .... nk !)
```

, where

```
n = n1 + n2 +...+ nk
```

here is the code for my second approach

```
def modexp(x, y, mod):
    res = 1
    if x==0 or x==1:
        return 1
    while y != 0:
        if y & 1 == 1:
            'if y is odd'
            res = (res * x) % mod
        x = (x * x) % mod
        y >>= 1
   return res

def modfact(n, mod):
    res = 1
    while n >= 1:
        res = (res * n) % mod
        n -= 1
    return res

mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
n, w, t, r = map(int, input().split())
resn = modfact(n, mod)
resw = modexp(modfact(w, mod), mod - 2, mod)
rest = modexp(modfact(t, mod), mod - 2, mod)
resr = modexp(modfact(r, mod), mod - 2, mod)
res = (resn*resw*rest*resr)%mod
print(res)
```

I just can't figure out why my second approach is wrong.Can someone provide any insights where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is suspicious:

```
res = resn//(resw*rest*resr)
```

`resw` and friends are modular inverses of the factorials, so they should be multiplied instead of divided. The final result should be modded out by 10**9 + 7.

Comment: updated the answer still my solution is not accepted

Comment: @aksam You still didn't mod out by `mod`.